# Accidentally pressed a key combination causing images to be hidden? How do I unhide?

Tags: digikam

I was selecting images to upload to an online photo album, when exactly the selection I had disappeared from the folder.  The images are still on the disk.  I guess I have accidentally pressed a key combination that causes those images to be hidden.  Is my guess correct?  If yes, how do I unhide?  If no, what might cause those images I had previously selected to be no longer shown, even though they're still on disk?

More inormation: Near the bottom, it says "No active filter".  Restarting digikam does not change the situation, nor does a refresh.  I am using Digikam 2.8.0.

I have also tried to rename the folder, and to rename all the files, but neither causes digikam to show the affected pictures (after a restart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images got **grouped** by accident.

Now I noticed that at one of the later images, there was a small icon saying `11`.  By right-clicking, then `group -> ungroup`, all images became visible again.